# PhpStorm - getting a simple look and feel

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm, phped

Just from  the time point that this  [youtube](https://youtu.be/rA9pkfyrVXI?t=129) video starts at, you see a very plain look and feel of the [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) 2017.3 IDE. I hope the left side project explorer pane ( which is not visible in the window) should also match with it accordingly.

At times, I can install a new theme which just changes the right side part (i.e. where we write code) of the IDE but the left side part (i.e. project explorer pane ) and other parts of the IDE horizontal bars  at the top part atc remain as they were before .

PhpStorm themes are available online, I know. But I think the look I see in the video is kinda default one. At the same time , from the PhpStorm [homepage](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) , you see that the look they display is a really bright one.

Exactly what steps do I need to follow ( steps to change Theme, Color etc) to get the look in the video or at least as much close to it as possible ?

If any more information is necessary to make the question more specific, I'll readily provide .

Answer (score 2):

Editor (and some other aspects) is controlled by Color Scheme. The actual GUI (including Project View/Structure panel) -- by GUI Theme.

To change the **GUI Theme**: `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance --> Theme`

- "Windows" (available on Windows OS only) and "IntelliJ" are light;
- "Darcula" is dark.

On Mac/Linux you may see a bit different list of available GUI Themes.

[image]

To change the **Color Scheme**: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme`

[image]

---

**HINT:** You can change them right from the Editor (no need to go into Settings) -- just use `View | Quick Switch Scheme...` ("Look and Feel" and "Color Scheme" items)

[image]

---

There are some 3rd party plugins that once installed will change both GUI Theme and Color Scheme to their own (e.g. "Material Theme" or "Afterglow") -- these two belong to dark styles.

Comment: 1) no way to reverse the GUI Theme and Color Scheme after those 3rd party plugins are installed ? 2) And what are the differences between Color Scheme and Theme ?

Comment: 1) Uninstall plugin 2) Check the very first sentence in my answer

Comment: 'Editor (and some other aspects) is controlled by Color Scheme. The actual GUI (including Project View/Structure panel) -- by GUI Theme.' -  1) so is the right part where we write code called the editor and the left part where the project structure is shown called the GUI Theme  ? 2) What are the some other aspects - the breadcrumb, some horizontal bars at the top etc ?

Comment: GUI = Graphical User Interface. Here it means the window itself, how dialogs/progress bar/buttons/tool windows/scroll bars/etc look. Editor -- it's where you write your code. "Some other aspects" -- places that allow to set the colors using Color Scheme (e.g. Terminal, VCS status etc -- I see no need to list them all here). P.S. There is no concrete "left" and "right" parts -- you can move tool windows to other sides. I for example have Structure on the left side and Project View panel on the right side ... so the Editor is in the middle.

Comment: ' I for example have Structure on the left side and Project View panel on the right side' - what is the difference between Structure and Project View panel  ?

Comment: How about checking the help pages: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html vs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structure-tool-window-file-structure-popup.html